# How to create a box and whisker plot tracking orders by day of the week in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, boxplot

I have already searched throuoghly both on google and stackoverflow, but cannot find an answer to this question:

My question is very similar to this but for Tableau: [Boxpplot on multiple columns - Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkJRE.png)[Box and whisker plot on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485644/box-and-whisker-plot-on-multiple-columns)

What I'd like to do is this: I have the amount of 3 different products that were sold on different dates. I'd like to do a boxplot to see the avg, max, and min, etc of the three products being sold. Below is a crude drawing of what I want to do:
[image: Boxplot example]

Here is sample data in CSV format:

Date,A Orders,B Orders,C Orders
"Wednesday, March 30, 2016",28,44,73
"Monday, September 5, 2016",37,36,55
"Friday, March 25, 2016",35,54,67
"Friday, September 16, 2016",32,58,58
"Tuesday, March 1, 2016",30,43,80
"Saturday, November 26, 2016",36,59,71
"Monday, November 21, 2016",28,44,72
"Sunday, March 13, 2016",27,47,67
"Thursday, February 4, 2016",32,51,54
"Tuesday, February 16, 2016",44,46,71
"Thursday, February 4, 2016",47,50,64
"Monday, September 19, 2016",36,41,77
"Friday, December 9, 2016",36,53,87
"Monday, March 28, 2016",32,64,71
"Sunday, October 16, 2016",30,58,59
"Friday, July 22, 2016",31,35,70
"Sunday, October 9, 2016",40,56,67
"Thursday, June 9, 2016",29,49,77
"Tuesday, November 29, 2016",16,44,59
"Thursday, January 28, 2016",38,64,81
"Sunday, January 24, 2016",30,48,81
"Monday, July 4, 2016",27,46,82
"Friday, August 26, 2016",32,47,68
"Monday, December 26, 2016",23,63,83
"Wednesday, February 17, 2016",15,40,67
"Monday, May 16, 2016",34,49,76
"Monday, July 4, 2016",35,46,63
"Monday, January 18, 2016",32,56,76
"Saturday, November 5, 2016",36,44,66
"Sunday, July 24, 2016",39,50,75
"Saturday, July 30, 2016",36,32,64
"Saturday, January 9, 2016",33,56,56
"Saturday, January 9, 2016",37,46,81
"Monday, July 18, 2016",25,55,68
"Wednesday, March 16, 2016",28,41,60
"Tuesday, February 9, 2016",16,40,63
"Friday, September 16, 2016",33,46,76
"Tuesday, January 5, 2016",36,62,86
"Monday, July 25, 2016",23,55,65
"Monday, June 6, 2016",22,46,76
"Saturday, December 17, 2016",38,44,74
"Tuesday, September 6, 2016",30,41,61
"Saturday, April 2, 2016",46,44,67
"Wednesday, February 3, 2016",35,52,69
"Monday, February 8, 2016",33,47,80
"Thursday, December 15, 2016",34,55,67
"Tuesday, December 13, 2016",34,65,83
"Friday, July 8, 2016",19,49,79
"Tuesday, February 9, 2016",24,48,68
"Tuesday, May 24, 2016",22,50,68
"Friday, March 4, 2016",33,57,61
"Friday, May 13, 2016",25,50,83
"Sunday, February 21, 2016",40,46,75
"Monday, October 10, 2016",23,68,53
"Saturday, June 18, 2016",35,51,59
"Tuesday, November 29, 2016",35,59,72
"Saturday, June 25, 2016",27,45,75
"Thursday, March 17, 2016",24,46,55
"Sunday, September 25, 2016",26,38,83
"Monday, May 9, 2016",24,44,58
"Saturday, May 21, 2016",30,58,57
"Monday, February 8, 2016",27,63,82
"Wednesday, January 20, 2016",37,49,85
"Friday, April 22, 2016",34,66,62
"Thursday, October 6, 2016",27,58,84
"Wednesday, August 31, 2016",19,46,68
"Thursday, July 7, 2016",31,60,78
"Sunday, October 23, 2016",29,43,77
"Thursday, October 13, 2016",42,52,84
"Thursday, May 12, 2016",42,51,63
"Saturday, September 24, 2016",23,45,85
"Monday, May 9, 2016",28,53,63
"Saturday, November 19, 2016",31,55,62
"Wednesday, February 17, 2016",30,39,62
"Sunday, February 28, 2016",33,52,73
"Saturday, May 28, 2016",28,49,58
"Monday, January 4, 2016",38,56,70
"Friday, January 29, 2016",37,64,74
"Friday, April 22, 2016",40,47,59
"Thursday, March 3, 2016",27,59,73
"Saturday, December 17, 2016",20,64,68
"Thursday, January 21, 2016",19,40,69
"Tuesday, December 13, 2016",33,45,67
"Thursday, January 7, 2016",31,53,64
"Wednesday, January 6, 2016",23,54,74
"Sunday, November 6, 2016",27,39,72
"Wednesday, September 14, 2016",18,46,81
"Thursday, March 31, 2016",45,37,77
"Wednesday, August 10, 2016",54,61,79
"Saturday, May 7, 2016",24,40,80
"Wednesday, February 10, 2016",32,50,63
"Wednesday, April 27, 2016",37,49,83
"Monday, April 18, 2016",36,46,68
"Sunday, August 7, 2016",28,39,82
"Tuesday, September 6, 2016",16,54,63
"Tuesday, September 13, 2016",26,52,70
"Monday, April 18, 2016",35,49,83
"Monday, December 26, 2016",27,52,70
"Thursday, March 24, 2016",23,49,63

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data did not work for me. I built the following example using the Sample Superstore dataset:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCEMJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use box and whisker plot under 'Show Me' in upper-right corner. Suggests you may need to turn off aggregation.

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_boxplot.htm